# Convert array to a list-Julia

Tags: julia

I am wanting to use the dbeta function in the Rmath package of Julia with the following call:

```
dbeta(x, 1, 25)
```

x is a 100 X 1 array, and when I try to use x with the dbeta function I get the following error:

```
ERROR: MethodError: no method matching dbeta(::Array{Float64,2}, ::Int64, ::Int64)
```

Is there a way to convert an array of numbers to a list of numbers in Julia? I am basically trying to work around the fact that x is an array. 
Thank you!

Comment: the error says `x` is of type `Array{Float64,2}` which means it's actually a `1 x 100` matrix, so you need `vec(x)` for converting it to a vector.

Comment: `100x1` and `1x100` arrays are _both_ matrices. Never the less, no arrays or vectors are accepted as inputs here. And there doesn't exist a `list` data structure. Perhaps he's thinking of `tuple`, which won't work either.

Comment: sorry for the misleading comment, that's a (bad/wrong)wild guess, I was on a phone and didn't test that Rmath function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Rmath version 0.4.0 has the following methods for `dbeta`:

```
julia> methods(dbeta)
# 2 methods for generic function "dbeta":
dbeta(x::Number, p1::Number, p2::Number) in Rmath at Rmath\src\Rmath.jl:192
dbeta(x::Number, p1::Number, p2::Number, give_log::Bool) in Rmath at Rmath\src\Rmath.jl:209
```

Which shows you that `dbeta` expects a scalar as its firs argument. Actually you get this hint when you run `dbeta(x, 1, 25)`:

```
julia> dbeta(x, 1, 25)
ERROR: MethodError: no method matching dbeta(::Array{Float64,2}, ::Int64, ::Int64)
Closest candidates are:
  dbeta(::Number, ::Number, ::Number) at \Rmath\src\Rmath.jl:192
  dbeta(::Number, ::Number, ::Number, ::Bool) at v0.6\Rmath\src\Rmath.jl:209
```

which guides you at the proper method signatures.

So how to solve your problem - this is pretty simple. Use broadcasting with `.` like this:

```
dbeta.(x, 1, 25)
```

and all works as expected. In general you can expect that this pattern should be used in almost all functions in Julia, like `sin` or `cos` in base, i.e. by default they accept scalars and you should use broadcasting with `.` to apply them to a vector. This is explained here https://docs.julialang.org/en/latest/manual/functions/#man-vectorized-1 in the Julia manual.

Comment: Wow, so simple! Thank you for your help!